# Group list by multiple conditions, LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have `Book` class:

```
public class Book
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public deciaml Price {get; set;}
}
```

And List of `books`:

```
List<Book> books = new List<Book>
    {
        new Book
        {
            Id = 1,
            Name = "AA",
            Price = 19.0000M
        },
        new Book
        {
            Id = 2,
            Name= "BB",
            Price = 18.0000M
        },
        new Book
        {
            Id = 3,
            Name = "CC",
            Price = 30.0000M
        },
        new Book
        {
            Id = 4,
            Name = "DD",
            Price = 9.0000M,
        },
    };
```

Now I want to group list by price rate, like cheap, medium, expensive:

for example, *cheap = 10,  medium = 20, expensive = 30*
grouped list would be like:

`List<(decimal category, List<Book> books)`

```
    {
       category: 10
       books: List<Book>() {Book {4, "DD", 9.0000M}},
       category: 20
       books: List<Book>() {Book {1, "AA", 19.0000M}, Book {2, "BB", 18.0000M}},
       category: 30
       books: List<Book>() {Book {3, "CC", 30.0000M}},
    }
```

**UPDATE**

```
books.GroupBy(book => book.Price).Select(group => (group.Key, group.ToList()));
```

I can get grouped list of books but, can not group by multiple conditions.

**UPDATE**

Thank you all for quick answers, seems `DotNet Developer`s answer shorter and sweet.

```
books.GroupBy(book => book.Price <= cheap ? cheap :
                    (book.Price > cheap && book.Price <= middle ? middle : expensive))
         .Select(group => (group.Key, group.ToList()))
```

Comment: What if a book costs more than `30.0000M`? In which category it belongs then?

Comment: Let's suppose there no book costs more than 30

Comment: That's a dangerous assumption to make. Essentially you say that if a single book costs more 30, the behavior of your program becomes undefined.

Comment: yes you are right, it's not real application, I'm just learning grouping list with multiple conditions usin LINQ

Comment: Thanks to everybody for quick response, and helping me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With ternary conditional operator

```
books.GroupBy(b => b.Price < 10 ? 10 : (b.Price < 20 ? 20 : 30));
```

Answer (score 1):

The `GroupBy` operator expects a function or expression that returns the group key. You can use this to return the group "name" based on the price :

```
var bins=books.GroupBy(b=> b.Price switch {  
                          <=10          =>"cheap", 
                          >10 and <= 20 => " medium", 
                          _             => "expensive"})
              .ToDictionary(g=>g.Key,g=>g);
```

The result is a dictionary with each category and its contents :

```
Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(bins));
-------
{
    " medium":[{"Id":1,"Name":"AA","Price":19.0000},{"Id":2,"Name":"BB","Price":18.0000}],
    "expensive":[{"Id":3,"Name":"CC","Price":30.0000}],
    "cheap":[{"Id":4,"Name":"DD","Price":9.0000}]
}
```

I used pattern matching in `GroupBy` to fit all conditions in a single lambda. This could be a separate function though :

```
string BookToBins(Book b)
{

    if (b.Price <= 10) return "cheap";
    if (b.Price <= 20) return "medium";
    return "expensive";
}

...
var bins=books.GroupBy(BookToBins)
              .ToDictionary(g=>g.Key,g=>g);
```

Answer (score 0):

First - add category to the list

```
var newBookList = BookList.Select(x=> new { Book = x, 
                                     Category = x.Price <= 10 ? 10 : 
                                                x.Price <= 20 ? 20 : 
                                                30 } ).ToList();
```

then Group By this Category :

```
var GroupedBooks = newBookList.GroupBy(x=>x.Category);
foreach(var category in GroupedBooks.Keys) {
         Console.WriteLine("category : {0}", category);
         foreach(var b in GroupedBooks[Keys].Select(x=>x.Book))
          Console.Write("Book {0}, \"{1}\", {2}",b.Id, b.Name, b.Price);
}
```

something like that?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not necessarily bound by specific category values, but rather want to group your books by price rates that are divisible by `10` (i.e. `10`, `20`, `30`, `40`, and so on), you could achieve this by rounding the `Price` up to the nearest `10` and use that as your group-by-value.

Here is an example, using [`Math.Ceiling()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.ceiling?view=net-6.0) to do the rounding:

```
Math.Ceiling(value / 10) * 10 // Round 'value' upwards to nearest 10
```

Applied as the group-by-condition:

```csharp
List<(decimal Category, List<Book> Books)> groupedBooks = books
    .GroupBy(book => Math.Ceiling(book.Price / 10) * 10,
        (category, booksInCategory) => ( 
            Category: category, 
            Books: booksInCategory.ToList() ))
    .OrderBy(gr => gr.Category)
    .ToList();
```

Using your provided example list for `books`, the resulting `groupedBooks` contains:

> Category: 10
> Book: { Id: 4    Name: DD    Price: 9.0000 }
>
> Category: 20
> Book: { Id: 1    Name: AA    Price: 19.0000 }
> Book: { Id: 2    Name: BB    Price: 18.0000 }
>
> Category: 30
> Book: { Id: 3    Name: CC    Price: 30.0000 }

Example fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ff0DNM).